# Azure SQL DTU level increase and decrease with powershell schedule

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, azure-devops

We have a REPORT database in Azure.
Every morning, we need some complex sql procedures to work inside that server.
Normally DTU level of this server is 0. but only in the mornings, it needs to be updated to DTU level 3. 
We are now making this manually by ourselves. But we want this to be automated via Powershell or anything.
how can we achieve this.
Can you show us the way please because we are .NET developers and don't know anything about scripting languages.

Thanks for reading and hope you can help us.

Comment: I have searched before asking. But I couldn't find anything about automatic DTU level increase and decrease. You can point us the way of learning powershell to make DTU automation. That would be enough. Thank you for comment anyway.

Comment: I suggest you use Azure Automation. Here's an example. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-Database-e957354f

Comment: Hi patron, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are powershell script, azure cli and API that you can use to manage Elastic Pools.

Powershell: For more information check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/set-azsqlelasticpool?view=azps-2.7.0)

```
Set-AzSqlElasticPool -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -ServerName "Server01" -ElasticPoolName "ElasticPool01" -Dtu 1000 -DatabaseDtuMax 100 -DatabaseDtuMin 20
```

Azure Cli: Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/elastic-pool?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-elastic-pool-update) for more information

```
az sql elastic-pool update -g mygroup -s myserver -n mypool -c
```

API: Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/elasticpools/update) for details.

```
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/elasticPools/{elasticPoolName}?api-version=2017-10-01-preview
```

Answer (score 0):

Single Azure SQL Database supports manual dynamic scalability, but not autoscale. For a more automatic experience, consider using elastic pools, which allow databases to share resources in a pool based on individual database needs. However, there are scripts that can help automate scalability for a single Azure SQL Database. For an example, see [Use PowerShell to monitor and scale a single SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-monitor-and-scale-database-powershell).

Hope this helps.